# Oracle SQL I cannot do group by

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

The error I'm getting is **Missing Expression**

Below is my SQL statement

```
select 
ecell_name, 
ecell_relation,
pmm_datetime,

pmHoExeOutAttLteInterFQci1 As_Exec_Attempt_Out
--pmHoExeOutSuccLteInterFQci1 As_Exec_Succes_Out, 
--(pmHoTooEarlyHoQci1) As Early_HO, (pmHoTooLateHoQci1)  As Late_HO, 
--(pmHoWrongCellReestQci1) As WrongCellReest_HO, 
--(pmHoWrongCellQci1) As WrongCell_HO, (pmHoOscQci1) As Osc_HO

from PMMCOUNTER_DB.LC_N_EUTRANCELLREL_D

where substr (ECELL_NAME,1,4) in 'BKPA' and pmm_datetime BETWEEN TO_DATE('14/06/2019','DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('15/06/2019','DD/MM/YYYY') and direction='Outgoing' 
and GROUP BY ecell_relation
```

Comment: `GROUP BY` should come after the `WHERE` clause and shouldn't be a part of it

Comment: For a question here is better if you rename some columns in order to make the question more understandable.
Reviewing your query, it seems to have an extra "and" before the GROUP BY

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to delete `and` orepator before your `group by`.
Second, you need to use all selected fields in your `group by`.
This should works:

```
 select ecell_name,
       ecell_relation,
       pmm_datetime,

       pmHoExeOutAttLteInterFQci1 As_Exec_Attempt_Out
--pmHoExeOutSuccLteInterFQci1 As_Exec_Succes_Out, 
--(pmHoTooEarlyHoQci1) As Early_HO, (pmHoTooLateHoQci1)  As Late_HO, 
--(pmHoWrongCellReestQci1) As WrongCellReest_HO, 
--(pmHoWrongCellQci1) As WrongCell_HO, (pmHoOscQci1) As Osc_HO

  from PMMCOUNTER_DB.LC_N_EUTRANCELLREL_D

 where substr(ECELL_NAME, 1, 4) in 'BKPA'
   and pmm_datetime BETWEEN TO_DATE('14/06/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND
       TO_DATE('15/06/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
   and direction = 'Outgoing' 
 GROUP BY ecell_relation, ecell_name, pmm_datetime, pmHoExeOutAttLteInterFQci1
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you for explaining it and correcting it.

Answer (score 0):

delete operator "and" before GROUP BY